# Error::unable to view all content of newly installed theme in magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento-2.0

[as per magento-2 official guide's instruction on changing theme on page-562]

newly installed theme folder in copied in

```
[magento_root]/app/design/frontend/Magento/[theme_name]/web
```

but it is showing only new themes title **porto ecommerce** and some other options and remaining contents of default website with no CSS and images..

How to display all the contents for new theme?